# excel vba to reopen excel file without saving

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code, it is about to reopen the current excel file.

```
   Sub CloseMe()

       Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), "OpenMe"
       ThisWorkbook.Close False
   End Sub

   Sub OpenMe()
       MsgBox "The file is reopened"
   End Sub
```

I am trying to make it applicable to activeworkbook, so i change

```
   ThisWorkbook.Close False
```

to

```
   ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

but it ended up close the activeworkbook but didnt reopen the file, any advise? Very sorry if this question seem silly to you.

Comment: I don't see where your code calls `Workbooks.Open`. Plus I think if you call `ActiveWorkbook.Close` and the macro is stored in active workbook, its execution will immediately stop.

Comment: the above code works well without workbooks.open. I wonder why when i use thisworkbook, it works well with the file for which this macro is written, but why i open other excel file and run this macro, it didnt work, it just close the the file without reopen it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub ReOpen()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks.Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a thought error ... when the workbook is closing, the contained VBA code is closing as well, so there's no code left to be executed 2 seconds later, and no object that would be the subject of any code.

This will only work if your closing/reopening logic is outside the sheet you want to close/reopen, and to be more specific, residing in a workbook that remains open all the time between closing/reopening the sheet you want to reopen.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get what do u mean, so u mean that the code cannot work for activeworkbook but only work for the thisworkbook where the macro is written?

Comment: no ... it can work for any ActiveWorkbook but - acc. to my tests - only if the actual code is residing in another workbook that you don't close

Answer (score 0):

I like this, which I adapted from ["How To Close And Reopen Active Workbook?"](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4883-excel-close-and-reopen-workbook.html#a1)

```
Sub ReOpen()
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadOnly, , False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    ActiveWorkbook.ChangeFileAccess xlReadWrite, , True
End Sub
```

It seems more elegant to me and warns if there are unsaved changes. While the original uses `ThisWorkbook`, I use `ActiveWorkbook` like @Taosique.